# Session loss and regeneration on page redirect

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I am having this problem for two days now. I am using the database driver of laravel and session data is regenerated on every page load therefore losing old session and populating the session table. I am using laravel 4.2.6 on localhost and below is my app/config/session.php.

```
return array(
 'driver' => 'database',
 'lifetime' => 120,
 'expire_on_close' => true,
 'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
 'connection' => 'mongodb',
 'table' => 'sessions',
 'lottery' => array(2, 100),
 'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
 'path' => '/',
 'domain' => null,
 'secure' => false,
);
```

Please help.